# Fedora 21 Samba Share Troubleshooting

Tags: fedora, systemd, samba, troubleshooting

I've recently upgraded my server's OS from CentOS 6 to Fedora 21.

I understand there have been a bunch of new changes regarding the SystemV vs SystemD updates but I cannot get my Samba share to work on the new server.

I have set it up exactly as on the CentOS machine.

```
yum install samba

created my /samba/Share directory with chmod 777

Change: workgroup = WORKGROUP

Change: hosts allow = 192.168.0. 127.0.0.1

[Share] 
    path = /samba/sharename 
    writable = yes 
    browsable = yes 
    guest ok = yes 
    guest only = yes 
    create mode = 777 
    directory mode = 777

disable SELinux

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=samba

systemctl start smb
systemctl start nmb

systemctl enable smb
systemctl enable nmb
```

Is there something else that I've missed?

Just an Update

The samba server IS running but no one can connect to it

We get the error

```
The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please choose another
```

Comment: Besides altering the `permanent` part of the firewall you also need to alter the `running` context, or restart your firewall to make the change effective.

Comment: Ok thank you I'm an idiot. It seems I've misunderstood the point of the new firewalld. It seems in the documentation it makes it sound as if the restart to apply changes is unnecessary but I guess it still is, thanks a bunch